# Removing NULL items from PySpark arrays

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null

How to remove the null items from `array(1, 2, null, 3, null)`?
Using the `array_remove` function doesn't help when we want to remove `null` items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following trick, using `array_except()` function:

`SELECT array_except(array(1, 2, null, 3, null), array(null))` returns `[1,2,3]`

Comment: you can also use higher order function filter like `filter(list,x-> x is not null)`

Comment: I get name 'null' is not defined.

Comment: @HarlanNelson if you use Pyspark, here is the syntax: 
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

F.filter(
            list, lambda x: x.isNotNull()
)

Answer (score 1):

**Spark 3.4+**

```py
F.array_compact("col_name")
```

[`array_compact`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_compact.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_compact) does not remove duplicates.

---

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([([1, 2, None, 3, None],)], ["c"])
df.show(truncate=0)
# +---------------------+
# |c                    |
# +---------------------+
# |[1, 2, null, 3, null]|
# +---------------------+

df = df.withColumn("c", F.array_compact("c"))

df.show()
# +---------+
# |        c|
# +---------+
# |[1, 2, 3]|
# +---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already accepted answer but I leave answer for a person who is working with java.

It could be done with `array_compact` [org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_compact](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#array_compact-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-)
But this is provided from spark 3.4.0.

And i took it from comment, thanks @HarlanNelson

```
# I have a text column; col(values) = "1.1,2,,,,,3.5, 4.1"
.withColumn("values_array", filter(split(col("values"), ",").cast("array<float>"), x -> x.isNotNull()))

# [1.1, 2, 3.5, 4.1]
```